# Zero-area-free embedding of points on the grid

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, polygons, lattice-polytopes

Given $n$, I am looking for the smallest $m$ such that there is an $n$ element subset $S$ of the $m\times m$ grid (i.e., $n$ points with integer coordinates in $[0,m]^2$) such that no matter how one picks a self-crossing polygon $P$ whose vertices are from $S$, the signed area of $P$ is never zero. Here signed area is defined as shading the regions of $P$ white and black so that touching regions receive different colors, and then taking the difference of the areas of the white and black regions. $P$ is required to be connected. A solution with small $m$ would have consequences in complexity theory, see [here](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2010/151/).

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, regions are considered touching even if they just have one point in common? and the $m\times m$ grid has $(m+1)^2$ points? For $n=4$, the smallest $n$ for which we can draw a self-crossing polygon, the answer is $m=2$, letting $S=\{\,(0,0),(0,1),(1,2),(2,0)\,\}$?

Comment: Yes to all! : )

Comment: How small is "small" for this purpose?

Comment: @Noam $m=poly(n)$ would be ideal.